# ¿Por qué se usa la palabra imbatible, mientras que invencible parece haber caido en desuso?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

En los ultimos años veo que la palabra *invencible* casi no se usa, y en general se prefiere usar imbatible.

Hace muchos años, en TV Argentina existía un juego llamado **El Invencible**, que por cuestiones de derechos de autor fue renombrado a **El Imbatible**. Pensé que en Argentina no se usaba, al menos en televisión, la palabra Invencible por este motivo, pero noto cada vez más la preferencia por la palabra **imbatible**, incluso fuera de Argentina.

¿A qué se debe esto?

Comment: Creo que es una sensación tuya. No estoy mucho en el asunto pero si es una palabra que le gusta proferir a los periodistas deportivos ya sabemos que la van a usar hasta el hartazgo y uno puede llegar a creer que la gente normal habla así todo el tiempo pero no. :)

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como se puede ver [en Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=invencible%2Cimbatible&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cinvencible%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binvencible%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInvencible%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cimbatible%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bimbatible%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BImbatible%3B%2Cc0), el uso de *imbatible* sigue una tendencia al alza y el de *invencible* parece que cayó desde mediados del siglo XX, pero en todo caso a aquella le queda aún mucho terreno que recorrer para alcanzar a *invencible*:

[image: Invencible vs imbatible]

En todo caso, esta gráfica recoge textos de todo el mundo hispanohablante, no sé si será el caso particular de Argentina. Podremos tratar de ver otros indicadores. Veamos por ejemplo el número de veces que ambas palabras se han consultado en el DLE durante 2019, restringidas a las búsquedas desde Argentina:

```
             invencible  imbatible
enero        11          10
febrero      35          17
marzo        45          25
abril        33          26
mayo         54          21
junio        38          46
julio        53          25
agosto       40          27
septiembre   51          16
octubre      41          38
noviembre    16          8
diciembre    3           2
```

En general sale vencedora *invencible*, con una media de 35 búsquedas al mes frente a las 21,75 de *imbatible*. Por último, el CORPES XXI, que incluye textos recientes, arroja un uso global de *invencible* de 3,52 casos por millón de palabras, mientras que *imbatible* se queda en 1,62 casos por millón de palabras.

La conclusión es que seguramente lo que percibas sea solo una impresión tuya, y no un reflejo de la realidad.